# Copy files from the local machine to the pod via deployment (initContainer)

Tags: kubernetes, copy, amazon-eks

I need to copy configuration files from the local directory c:/dev/project/eks/rules to /etc/traefik

[Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjhRK.png)

[Result (error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3les.png)

[Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53mRl.png)

I needed to copy the files before starting the main container. How to do this?

Comment: Can you put the files into a ConfigMap, and mount that as a volume?  This will work better for plain-text files than the PNG images you've included in the question, but configuration files tend to be plain text.